# Is there a way to run protractor tests in parallel by opening a browser instance for each test?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I am facing synchronisation issues with my protractor tests and I would like to run my tests in parallel in contrast to my actual settings. In fact at the moment my tests run one after the other.
I know how to this with TestsNG not sure how to do it with Jasmin Framework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 0.19.0 version of Protractor, you can run tests in parallel using the `multiCapabilities` option:

**protractor.conf.js**

```
multiCapabilities: [{
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}, {
  'browserName': 'chrome'
}]
```

from [Browser setup - Protractor docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md)

[This issue](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/381) seems to fit your case.

For now, Protractor doesn't allow to set Webdriver `maxSessions` option, there is a [more global discussion](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/569) to include this feature among others.

**EDIT:** multiCapabilities was introduced to run tests in parallel under different browsers, but in your case, you can use it to run multiple instances of the same ;)

Comment: Thanks for you answer, my concern is not about distributing tests between different browser, at lease not yet. What I would like to do is to run tests in parallel as oppose to one after the other using the same browser in order to avoid synchronisation issue.

Comment: Did you try to set the same browser in `multiCapabilities`? I tested it, it's working for me :)

Comment: I have tried this now and it run two instances of firefox but it run the same test twice what I would like to do is run two different tests in parallel. Do you mind we continue this in cha?

Comment: No problem to move to chat for me, but I don't know how to do it manually :/ The [support sharding](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/569) feature request seems to be exactly what you want to do, no?

Comment: I don' know neither!! well now I am able to share my tests between browsers. However I am facing issues when running many tests one after one in the same browser only the first tests runs.

Comment: No in fact the first tests run with all its subtests 'it' then the second starts and blocks after logging in. Then I get element ni visible error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49125/discussion-between-glepretre-and-ziwdigforbugs)

Answer (score 10):

To split tests between two browsers,

```
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
multiCapabilities: [
    {
        "browserName": "chrome",        
        shardTestFiles: true,
        maxInstances: 2,
        specs: ['login.js', 'login2.js', 'login.js', 'login2.js']
    },
    {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "count": 1
        specs: ['login2.js']
    },
],
```

You can use both "count" as well "maxInstances"
This is what worked best for me ..

```
            "browserName": "chrome",        
            shardTestFiles: true,
            maxInstances: 2,
            specs: ['login.js', 'login2.js', 'login.js', 'login2.js']
```

this would run 4 tests divided equally(or may not equally) in two different chrome browsers.