# Tests are running sequentially in protractor even when shard files is true

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am running the tests using protractor .I have 3 specs file but still it runs sequentially 
What am i missing here ?
Code :

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args: ['--headless', "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1080"]

    },
    // Ability to run the tests in parallel.
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 2
},
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run protractor tests in parallel by opening a browser instance for each test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22199711/is-there-a-way-to-run-protractor-tests-in-parallel-by-opening-a-browser-instance)

Comment: I think you also need to set `maxSessions`. The docs say that default is set to unlimited but in my experience it doesn't seem to work unless you also set that value in the config.